# Three.js cylinder example keeps drawing torus

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to get a basic THREE.js example to work and modify it from there on out but it just keeps outputting a torus, no matter what I change.

I've copied the exact code from the docs page into a JSFiddle and again I get a torus.

Here is the docs page example:
[CylinderGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry)

And here is the jsfiddle with the torus: https://jsfiddle.net/ded9grxn/

I've tried adding the code from the docs page to the example like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 20, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
{
    color: 0x156289,
    emissive: 0x072534,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});

mesh.add(
    new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material
    )
);
```

But to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Follow this example instead: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you fiddle does not work is that the script you invoke (https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/js/geometry.js) looks at the hash in the URL of the window to select the object.
If you go to
https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#CylinderGeometry
you get the cylinder.
If you go to
https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html
you get the default, which is a torus.

For the reason why your modification does not work, we need more information about how you performed the modif (what did you remove, where did you add).

---

(Edit) in the fiddle, after doing your modification, do not forget to remove the line

```
        var options = chooseFromHash( mesh );
```

this is where your script invokes the function in geometry.js that will set the mesh according to the hash in the URL